# How much faster is training on an AWS GPU enabled instance compared to training on 8-core CPU laptop?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deep-learning, bert-language-model

I'm working on fine-tuning a BERT model that takes about 1 hour 20 minutes per epoch.  I'm curious about how much more quickly I can expect this model to run after migrating to a g3s.xlarge.  Looking for a percentage time savings / very ballpark estimate of runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your workload is suitable and things are set up well then 4 to 5 times faster

see https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8751930